# Tuning Random Forest results in max_features parameter taking a value of 1. Why?

Tags: random-forest, hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization, tuning

I did a bayesian optimization tuning for parameters of random forest. With 200 iterations, it seems like 70% of the times, very low values (read 1 or 2) of max_features seems to produce better (marginally, 10 bp. , but still) recall scores. I did tuning and evaluation using 3 fold cross validation. Is there an over/under-fitting here?

I tried Bayesian optimization with 3 fold cross validation with 200 iterations. The sample size is 100K observations. max_feature space was [1:36].

Comment: It may be useful to know more about the data you are using. How many samples are you training on and how many features are you using? Also, how are you sampling value of `max_features` to test?

Comment: Have you tried running a single decision tree? You could check if it also uses a single feature and try to understand the splits there. Also I'd be curious if the feature chosen is always the same/changes.

Comment: @A.Bollans, unfortunately I did not understand your last question. max_features can take any value between 1 and 36, where 36 is the max number of features.

Comment: What other hyperparameters are you tuning, and what values do they end up taking? Which language/package?